Create store with zustand in Nextjs craeteStore()() vs createStore()
I was using zustand in react, now I start learning Next and try to set up zustand store, in documentation they create store like so:
createStore<CounterStore>()((set) => ({
    ...initState,
    decrementCount: () => set((state) => ({ count: state.count - 1 })),
    incrementCount: () => set((state) => ({ count: state.count + 1 })),
  }))

but code below work as well
createStore<CounterStore>((set) => ({
    ...initState,
    decrementCount: () => set((state) => ({ count: state.count - 1 })),
    incrementCount: () => set((state) => ({ count: state.count + 1 })),
  }))

documentation: https://docs.pmnd.rs/zustand/guides/nextjs
here are full example:
// src/stores/counter-store.ts
import { createStore } from 'zustand/vanilla'

export type CounterState = {
  count: number
}

export type CounterActions = {
  decrementCount: () => void
  incrementCount: () => void
}

export type CounterStore = CounterState & CounterActions

export const defaultInitState: CounterState = {
  count: 0,
}

export const createCounterStore = (
  initState: CounterState = defaultInitState,
) => {
  return createStore<CounterStore>()((set) => ({
    ...initState,
    decrementCount: () => set((state) => ({ count: state.count - 1 })),
    incrementCount: () => set((state) => ({ count: state.count + 1 })),
  }))
/*
this works as well
return createStore<CounterStore>((set) => ({
    ...initState,
    decrementCount: () => set((state) => ({ count: state.count - 1 })),
    incrementCount: () => set((state) => ({ count: state.count + 1 })),
  }))
*/
}

//what to use, what is difference
